# Compare difference between comma separated strings

Tags: php, string, compare

I have 2 strings and i'd like to compare the difference and use the values of those items that are different. For example:

```
$stringA = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
$stringB = "1, 2, 4, 5, 6"
```

So the difference with stringB is that the '3' is missing and '6' is added.

I'd like to perform a function that uses the values '3' and '6'. To put this in context, imagine the strings are used in a MySQL query where I want to update only the records with id 3 and 6 as they have changed so need updating but the rest remain the same so no need to update the database records for those. I hope that makes sense?

How would I get the differences using PHP and ensure the result is again a string with comma separated values? i.e

```
$stringDifference = "3, 6"
```

Comment: is the string always 5 numbers long?

Comment: Try it with php array_diff function. explode the both string into array then get difference and again use implode function to convert array to string.

Comment: No the string can have more or less values at any time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran through the code on my machine, this will solve the trick

```
$stringA = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
$stringB = "1, 2, 4, 5, 6";

$stringA = explode(',', $stringA);
$stringB = explode(',', $stringB);

$Difference_1 = array_diff($stringA, $stringB); // Check string A Against String B
$Difference_2 = array_diff($stringB, $stringA); // Check String B against String A
$Difference = array_merge($Difference_1, $Difference_2); // Merge the two difference arrays together 
$Difference = implode(',', $Difference); // Convert to a string
echo "The Difference Between The Two Is: ".$Difference; // Echo the difference
```

---

**Update**

```
function Differences ($Arg1, $Arg2){
    $Arg1 = explode (',', $Arg1);
    $Arg2 = explode (',', $Arg2);

    $Difference_1 = array_diff($Arg1, $Arg2);
    $Difference_2 = array_diff($Arg2, $Arg1);
    $Diff = array_merge($Difference_1, $Difference_2);
    $Difference = implode(',', $Diff);
    return "The Difference Between The Two Is: ".$Difference;
}

$stringA = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
$stringB = "1, 2, 4, 5, 6";


// Call By:

echo Differences($stringA, $stringB);
```

Sorry for the delay with the update. I have been getting used to PHPStorm as a new script editor.

Comment: So so close! I just tried the code and whilst it does say '3' is different, it doesn't say anything about the '6' in the $Difference string?

Comment: I just noticed that now. I'm working on a fix for it now. bare with me

Comment: I think it must be reversed, array_diff($stringB, $stringA) will find 6

Comment: @SomyA Reverse prints 6 alone

Comment: Yeah just tried that too. Have to ensure this works regardless of the sort order of the values and whether the strings have the same number of values or not. Appreciate the help!

Comment: of course, it must joins result from 2 operation, ex: array_merge(array_diff($stringA, $stringB), array_diff($stringB, $stringA));

Comment: @Bobster4300 Just converting this into a function for universal reference

Comment: Perfect! Worked a treat. Thanks Daryl and Somy. Giving Daryl the answer as I got the full code :)  Thanks heaps guys.

Comment: @Bobster4300 Please see my update. This chunk has been converted into a Function for a universal reference

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDif(stringA, stringb){
    $stra = explode(",", $stringA);
    $strb = explode(",", $stringB);
    $viola = array_diff($stra,$strb);
    return  $voila
}
```

Comment: A bit more context would improve this answer.